# wildcard expansion in buffer

Tags: debugging, minibuffer, wildcard

I'm debugging with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) in emacs and one of the parameters to the program I'm debugging is a list of regular expressions wrapped in quotes. Basically,

```
pdb someProgram.py 'regex .* .*'
```

from the minibuffer, I think.

The problem is that shell expansion happens here for some reason and the `.*` becomes expanded to a file wildcard pattern and becomes a list of all files in the current directory that start with `.` including `..` and any hidden files.

This doesn't happen if I'm running the program from the standard command line like so:

```
python someProgram.py 'regex .* .*'
```

Why is the expansion happening in the minibuffer? And how do I prevent it from happening?